# WordPress htaccess private folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

When I use this htaccess code in local environment it works perfectly. But when I upload it to server it doesn't work at all. I started to search problem and it seems like Lyxx shows errors on both lines. Can You guys help me to solve this problem, here is the code:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-content/uploads/private/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(private/.*)$ wp-pv-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L,NC] </IfModule>`

This code disables access to all content inside private folder if user is not logged in.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @charankumar the problem is that i get no error it just doesn't work and Lyxx shows these two lines highlighted red